# Free currency converter fixer.io stopped working

Tags: api, currency, magento2.2.3, currency-rates

Magento ver. 2.2.3

Seems today fixer.io stopped working.
It was the only service that still works for currency rates.
If I try to reach the url from web browser I get this

```
0   "#################################################################################################################################"
1   "#                                                                                                                               #"
2   "# IMPORTANT - PLEASE UPDATE YOUR API ENDPOINT                                                                                   #"
3   "#                                                                                                                               #"
4   "# This API endpoint is deprecated and has now been shut down. To keep using the Fixer API, please update your integration       #"
5   "# to use the new Fixer API endpoint, designed as a simple drop-in replacement.                                                  #"
6   "# You will be required to create an account at https://fixer.io and obtain an API access key.                                   #"
7   "#                                                                                                                               #"
8   "# For more information on how to upgrade please visit our Github Tutorial at: https://github.com/fixerAPI/fixer#readme          #"
9   "#                                                                                                                               #"
a   "#################################################################################################################################"
```

You can still get a free account, but code change needed to make it works with new API.

Does anybody know if a fix coming with the next upgrade of Magento?

Alternatively in Magento 1.9.3.8 I'm getting currency rates from [here](https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/), by custom module.

Does one already exist that use this service?

If there are no answers to these questions, the only solution will be to write a new custom module.

I hope for an escape...

Comment: I guess this will need to be changed to get it to work: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Directory/Model/Currency/Import/FixerIo.php#L16

For the API_KEY the scope config seems to be already there so shouldn't be too tricky to add a new field in the config, only question is where should this be added in.

Comment: This is the step to write e new module. In this case i prefer to use The Free Currency Converter API service. At list it doesn't need any subscription.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Free Currency Converter API module:

> app/code/MyCompany/FreeCurrencyConverter/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyCompany_FreeCurrencyConverter" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Directory"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/MyCompany/FreeCurrencyConverter/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\Config">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="servicesConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fcc" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Free Currency Converter</item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">MyCompany\FreeCurrencyConverter\Model\Currency\Import\Fcc</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/MyCompany/FreeCurrencyConverter/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <currency>
            <fcc>
                <timeout>100</timeout>
                <delay>1</delay>
            </fcc>
        </currency>
    </default>
</config>
```

> app/code/MyCompany/FreeCurrencyConverter/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="currency">
            <group id="fcc" translate="label" sortOrder="41" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Free Currency Converter</label>
                <field id="timeout" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Connection Timeout in Seconds</label>
                </field>
                <field id="delay" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Connection Delay Time in Seconds</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> app/code/MyCompany/FreeCurrencyConverter/Model/Currency/Import/Fcc.php

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\FreeCurrencyConverter\Model\Currency\Import;
class Fcc extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\AbstractImport
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/convert?q={{CURRENCY_FROM}}_{{CURRENCY_TO}}';
    /**
     * HTTP client
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient
     */
    protected $_httpClient;
    /**
     * Core store config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    protected $jsonHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
    ) {
        parent::__construct($currencyFactory);
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_httpClient = new \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient();
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $currencyFrom
     * @param string $currencyTo
     * @param int $retry
     * @return float|null
     */
    protected function _convert($currencyFrom, $currencyTo, $retry = 0)
    {
        $url = str_replace('{{CURRENCY_FROM}}', $currencyFrom, self::CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL);
        $url = str_replace('{{CURRENCY_TO}}', $currencyTo, $url);
        try {
            sleep($this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'currency/fcc/delay',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            ));
            $response = $this->_httpClient->setUri(
                $url
            )->setConfig(
                [
                    'timeout' => $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                        'currency/fcc/timeout',
                        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                    ),
                ]
            )->request(
                'GET'
            )->getBody();
            $resultKey = $currencyFrom.'_'.$currencyTo;
            $data = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($response);
            $results = $data['results'][$resultKey];
            $queryCount = $data['query']['count'];
            if( !$queryCount &&  !isset($results)) {
                $this->_messages[] = __('We can\'t retrieve a rate from %1.', $url);
                return null;
            }
            return (float)$results['val'];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($retry == 0) {
                $this->_convert($currencyFrom, $currencyTo, 1);
            } else {
                $this->_messages[] = __('We can\'t retrieve a rate from %1.', $url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**enjoy!**

**EDIT:**

as [Bizzy Bee](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/228880/15051) says:

Don't forget the following file to get it all going properly:

> app/code/MyCompany/FreeCurrencyConverter/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MyCompany_FreeCurrencyConverter',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

Comment: Hello Patal, can you offer download link for complete modul?

Comment: @MatthiasJaekle sorry, there is no way to upload this module here as far as i can see, but you got all files needed in this post. You should only add registration.php.

Comment: @krybbio you could use github, bitbucket, or gitlab with a public repo

Comment: @Rian feel free to do it. ;-)

Comment: @krybbio  Thanks for this helpful post...!

Comment: I've added this code to github - https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_ext_free_rates Thanks to @krybbio and all other guys.

Comment: Great solution and thanks @AlexGusev for the code on github, works perfectly

Answer (score 4):

It seems we need to subscribe Basic **$10/month** plan because Fixer new free plan offers only Euro base currency.
If you purchase $10/month plan, you can fix this issue editing:

> [root]/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency/Import/FixerIo.php

line 16
replace

```
const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}';
```

with

```
const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=1234yourkey5678&base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}';
```

It's better to wait some nice guy will create a new module with free converter API.

Comment: i am a nice guy

Comment: Wow! That's quick!

Comment: @krybbio Yes, your module works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Free Fixer.IO account is working fine, if your base currency is EUR. Converting to lot of different currencies is possible for free. 1000 API request per month.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the module code!

Don't forget the following file to get it all going properly:

> app/code/MyCompany/FreeCurrencyConverter/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MyCompany_FreeCurrencyConverter',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend on @lizenial's answer: 
Modifying core code is never a good idea, that's why you can override the original class, though (as far as I know) it requires overriding the entire class as it mostly consists of private methods, which we cannot modify using plugins.

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Currency\Import\FixFixerIo" />
</config>
```

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="currency" translate="label" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <tab>general</tab>
            <group id="fixerio" sortOrder="35" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <field id="api_key" translate="label,comment" type="text" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Api key</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[New updated API now requires an access key and a new URL.]]></comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Model/Currency/Import/FixFixerIo.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Currency\Import;

use \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class FixFixerIo extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo
{
    private $scopeConfig;

    const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}&access_key='; // changed constant

    const API_KEY_CONFIG_PATH = 'currency/fixerio/api_key';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($currencyFactory, $scopeConfig, $httpClientFactory);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @override
     * @see \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo::fetchRates()
     */
    public function fetchRates()
    {
        $data = [];
        $currencies = $this->_getCurrencyCodes();
        $defaultCurrencies = $this->_getDefaultCurrencyCodes();

        foreach ($defaultCurrencies as $currencyFrom) {
            if (!isset($data[$currencyFrom])) {
                $data[$currencyFrom] = [];
            }
            $data = $this->convertBatch($data, $currencyFrom, $currencies);
            ksort($data[$currencyFrom]);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $currencyFrom
     * @param array $currenciesTo
     * @return array
     * @override
     * @see \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo::convertBatch()
     */
    private function convertBatch($data, $currencyFrom, $currenciesTo)
    {
        $currenciesStr = implode(',', $currenciesTo);
        $url = str_replace('{{CURRENCY_FROM}}', $currencyFrom, self::CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL);
        $url = str_replace('{{CURRENCY_TO}}', $currenciesStr, $url);

        set_time_limit(0);
        try {
            $response = $this->getServiceResponse($url);
        } finally {
            ini_restore('max_execution_time');
        }

        foreach ($currenciesTo as $currencyTo) {
            if ($currencyFrom == $currencyTo) {
                $data[$currencyFrom][$currencyTo] = $this->_numberFormat(1);
            } else {
                if (empty($response['rates'][$currencyTo])) {
                    $this->_messages[] = __('We can\'t retrieve a rate from %1 for %2.', $url, $currencyTo);
                    $data[$currencyFrom][$currencyTo] = null;
                } else {
                    $data[$currencyFrom][$currencyTo] = $this->_numberFormat(
                        (double)$response['rates'][$currencyTo]
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $url
     * @param int $retry
     * @return array|mixed
     * @override
     * @see \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo::convertBatch()
     */
    private function getServiceResponse($url, $retry = 0)
    {
        $accessKey = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::API_KEY_CONFIG_PATH, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $url .= $accessKey;
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient $httpClient */
        $httpClient = $this->httpClientFactory->create();
        $response = [];

        try {
            $jsonResponse = $httpClient->setUri(
                $url
            )->setConfig(
                [
                    'timeout' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                        'currency/fixerio/timeout',
                        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                    ),
                ]
            )->request(
                'GET'
            )->getBody();

            $response = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($retry == 0) {
                $response = $this->getServiceResponse($url, 1);
            }
        }
        return $response;
    }

}
```

I know this (probably) isn't the cleanest solution as it overwrites pretty much the entire class but if any of you have a cleaner solution feel free to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution of updating the fixerIo.php file and for the sake of testing I even changed the store base currency to EUR, however, I get the following error after I have amended the code:

> Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency/Import/FixerIo.php on line 6

Are there any other changes needed besides for those in the fixerio.php file?

Comment: I think this should not be the answer. If you have some query, you can comment on the post or ask your own question by clicking on Ask Question button.

Comment: You are right. I'm new to StackExchange, therefore, I cannot comment... Start a new thread is probably also not the right way forward... It's a bit of a chicken and egg situation here.

Comment: I think you have made some mistakes in editing the file. Anyway, modify core file is always wrong. Use one of the two modules in the discussion instead.