# Import currency rate does not work on Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm setting up a website with multiple currencies.

When I tried to import currency rate from the back-end,

> back-end -> Store -> Currency Rate

It didn't work as I expected.

All the service can't return the rate.

I searched this issue on the internet and found out this is the Magento issue. 
Does anyone have any ideal to fix it?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution by my self. The Fixer API is changed and requires an API key. If we use the free plan account, we can convert the currency rate from EUR only.

I decided to make my own extension to implement other free currency convert services. You guys can check it in here https://github.com/thanhdv2811/Magento-2-Currency-Convert

I implemented 3 services:

```
https://currencylayer.com/
https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/
https://frankfurter.app/
```

Comment: you need to update module so it can work with magento 2.2.* by updating composer.json

Comment: This doesn't work for me,

Answer (score 3):

This API endpoint is deprecated and has now been shut down. To keep using the Fixer API, please update your integration to use the new Fixer API endpoint, designed as a simple drop-in replacement.

You will be required to create an account at https://fixer.io and obtain an API access key.

Please read more [here](https://github.com/fixerAPI/fixer#readme).

Alternatively, you can check other ways to integrate currency conversion [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228588/free-currency-converter-fixer-io-stopped-working/228880#228671) (to integrate **Free Currency Converter API**) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228588/free-currency-converter-fixer-io-stopped-working/228880#228647) (to use **Fixer.io paid API**).